# séries de taylor em python sem ângulo e com margem de erro

Tags: python, matemática

Olá! Preciso montar um programa que calcule seno, cosseno e exponencial de séries de taylor no Python, mas o programa não pode aceitar um valor de ângulo, apenas o x, o número de termos da série e um erro aceitável. 
tentei fazer isso mas dá errado porque os valores não batem com o que deveria dar. o enunciado é esse:

Considere a s funções abaixo:

> sen(x) = x/1! – x3/3! + x5/5! - . . . + (-1)k . x2k+1/(2k+1)! + . . .
>
> cos(x) = 1 – x2/2! + x4/4! – x6/6! + . . . + (-1)k . x2k/(2k)! + . . .
>
> ex = 1 + x + x2/2! + x3/3! + x4/4! + ... + xn/n! + ...

Há 2 formas de fazer a aproximação:
1. Calcular a soma de um certo número de termos. Quanto maior a quantidade de termos melhor será a aproximação.
2. Calcular a soma até encontrar um termo cujo valor absoluto seja bem pequeno, pois a partir de um certo termo, o seguinte será sempre menor em valor absoluto.

O seu programa deve calcular o valor das funções acima usando os dois métodos de aproximação para vários valores de n (número de termos) e eps (valor bem pequeno). Também deve comparar os valores calculados com o obtido usando a função existente no módulo math do Python.

obrigada!! :)

def serie():

## Para a função seno

```
def sen():
    import math

    x = float(input("Entre com o valor de x: "))
    n = int(input("Entre com o valor de n, sendo ele positivo: "))
    eps = float(input("Entre com um valor bem pequeno: "))

    while n <= 0:
        n = int(input("Entre com um valor positivo de n: "))

    while eps <= 0 or eps >1:
        eps = float(input("Entre com um valor bem pequeno: "))

    seno = math.sin(x)
    print("O seno vale", seno)


    #Para calcular o seno com base na soma de termos
    sen_n = 0
    sinal_n = 0
    fat_n = 1

    for k in range (1, n + 1 ,2):
        fat_n = 1

        for i in range (2, k + 1):
            fat_n = fat_n * i

        sen_n += (pow(-1, sinal_n) * pow(x, k)) / fat_n
        sinal_n += 1
        sen1 = sen_n

    print("sen1 vale", sen1)

    print("A diferença pelo método 1 é", abs(sen1 - seno))

    sen()
serie()
```

Comment: Por favor dê uma olhada na minha resposta, e veja o que falta - gostaria de entender a questão da margem de erro e então editá-la, se possível.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As tuas funções

```
sen(x) = x/1! – x3/3! + x5/5! - ... + (-1)k . x2k+1/(2k+1)! + ...
cos(x) = 1 – x2/2! + x4/4! – x6/6! + ... + (-1)k . x2k/(2k)! + ...
ex(x) = 1 + x + x2/2! + x3/3! + x4/4! + ... + xn/n! + ...
```

podem ser generalizadas para

```
f(y) = ∑ fn(n) / fd(n)! × y^(fe(n))
```

ou seja (tomando os primeiros 5 termos):

```
import math
def taylor(fn,fd,fe,x,iter=5):
  s=0
  for i in range(0, iter):
    s +=  fn(i)/math.factorial(fd(i))*math.pow(x, fe(i))
  return s

def seno(x):
  return taylor(lambda n: (-1)**n,
                lambda n: 2*n +1,
                lambda n: 2*n +1, x)

def cosseno(x):
  return taylor(lambda n: (-1)**n, 
                lambda n: 2*n,
                lambda n: 2*n, x)

def exp(x): return taylor(lambda n:1, lambda n:n, lambda n:n, x)
```

Para testar...

```
def rad(x): return x/180*math.pi

r=rad(31)
print(math.sin(r), seno(r), math.sin(r)-seno(r))
## 0.5150380749100542 0.5150380749391384 -2.90842905315003e-11
```

Junta-lhe agora as várias estratégias de terminação ou de erro

Answer (score 1):

> Gostaria de entender o que significa `k` no enunciado, e também sobre o erro (sou péssimo em matemática). Se você ainda não resolveu essa questão, aguardarei comentários seus aqui.

Dito isso, você pode fazer as somas dos termos das séries de Taylor, assim:

```
# Primeiro fazemos a conversão para radianos
def para_radianos(x):
    return x/180*math.pi

# aqui nós fazemos a divisão e o fatorial
def taylor(x, i):
return math.pow(x, i)/math.factorial(i)
```

E agora precisamos fazer a sequência de somas e subtrações, para isso, criamos um *loop*:

```
# para o cálculo do seno
def calcula_seno(x, termos): # recebe o ângulo e no. de termos
    y = 3
    z = 0
    while True: # só para quando alcançarmos o número de termos
        z = z - taylor(x, y)
        y = y + 2
        z = z + taylor(x, y)
        y = y + 2
        if y >= termos: # alcançamos?
            break
    return x+z
```

E chamamos a função desse jeito:

```
angulo = 32
radianos = para_radianos(angulo)
calcula_seno(radianos, 1)
```

> Para o cálculo do cosseno, a função não é muito diferente desta. Segue um exemplo completo:

```
import math

# rad
def para_radianos(x):
    return x/180*math.pi

# taylor
def taylor(x, i):
    return math.pow(x, i)/math.factorial(i)

# sen
def calcula_seno(x, termos):
    y = 3
    z = 0
    while True:
        z = z - taylor(x, y)
        y = y + 2
        z = z + taylor(x, y)
        y = y + 2
        if y >= termos:
            break
    return x+z

# cos
def calcula_cosseno(x, termos):
    y = 2
    z = 0
    while True:
        z = z - taylor(x, y)
        y = y + 2
        z = z + taylor(x, y)
        y = y + 2
        if y >= termos:
            break
    return 1+z

# testa seno
print('testa seno:')
seno_math = math.sin(para_radianos(32))
seno_taylor = calcula_seno(para_radianos(32), 5)
print('math.sin: ' + str(seno_math))
print('taylor:   ' + str(seno_taylor))
print('')
# testa cosseno
print('testa cosseno:')
cosseno_math = math.cos(para_radianos(45))
cosseno_taylor = calcula_cosseno(para_radianos(45), 5)
print('math.sin: ' + str(cosseno_math))
print('taylor:   ' + str(cosseno_taylor))
```

> Resultado:
>   [image: resultado da execução do programa]